# Configure custom log file location for kubectl logs

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod running a spring-boot app.
When I run the `kubectl logs` command I only see the Spring boot logo plus other 4 or 5 lines like:

```
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of reactor.core.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

How can I configure a different logfile location to show instead?
Thanks.